# How to position <paper-input>s horizontally

Tags: polymer

I'd like to position two `<paper-input>`s horizontally like this:

[image: screenshot]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions to your problem. The simplest is to add a CSS class to your input element, which should contain the `display:inline-block` rule.

```
.inline-element {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And apply your class to the `<paper-input>`s:

```
<paper-input label="Email" class="inline-element"></paper-input>
<paper-input label="Sub ID" class="inline-element"></paper-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymer way of doing it is by [iron-flex-layout](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout) element.

When using it take care of this note from the docs:

> ...You must do this in any element that uses any of the iron-flex-layout
>   styles.

So, after all imports(element & style), it should look as this:

```
<div class="layout horizontal">
        <paper-input label="Email"></paper-input>
        <paper-input label="ID"></paper-input>
</div>
```